# Spring + jsp + selectivity.js - how to read selectivity config from file builded on java site

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I am using in my spring app [selectivity.js](https://arendjr.github.io/selectivity/) which is a selection library with nice "tags look". Right now I have js file where I configure selectivity data:

```js
/**
 * 
 */
$(document).ready(
 function() {
  $('#single-input-with-labels').selectivity(
  {
   multiple : true,
   items : 
   [ 
    {
     text : 'City',
     children : [{
      id : 1,
      text : 'cityName1'
     }, {
      id : 2,
      text : 'cityName2'
     }, {
      id : 3,
      text : 'cityName3'
     }]
    }, {
     text : 'Type',
     children : [{
      id : 4,
      text : '2.1.typeName1'
     }, {
      id : 5,
      text : '2.2.typeName2'
     }, {
      id : 6,
      text : '2.3.typeName3'
     }]
    }
   ],
   placeholder : 'ie. City, Type, ...',
   searchInputPlaceholder : 'Type to search'
  });
 }
);
```

But I need to have this configuration :

```js
{
   multiple : true,
   items : 
   [ 
    {
     text : 'City',
     children : [{
      id : 1,
      text : 'cityName1'
     }, {
      id : 2,
      text : 'cityName2'
     }, {
      id : 3,
      text : 'cityName3'
     }]
    }, {
     text : 'Type',
     children : [{
      id : 4,
      text : '2.1.typeName1'
     }, {
      id : 5,
      text : '2.2.typeName2'
     }, {
      id : 6,
      text : '2.3.typeName3'
     }]
    }
   ],
   placeholder : 'ie. City, Type, ...',
   searchInputPlaceholder : 'Type to search'
  }
```

in some file for example: "myData.txt". I will build this txt file programmatically from java site after analysis of some data. In next step I need to read this structure from the js function :

```js
/**
 * 
 */
$(document).ready(
 function() {
  $('#single-input-with-labels').selectivity(
          /* here I want to read this structure from the generated txt file
  );
 }
);
```

Do you know how to read this structure of data from another text file to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the configuration in a JSON file that you can load using $.ajax()? Then you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax('/url/to/my/config.json').done(function(config) {
        $('#single-input-with-labels').selectivity(config);
    });
});
```